Typescript search and pagination
The issue with pagination of the search results not showing all the search results returned, it shows nothing or only partial search results.
like when i search a input from 50 entries it is showing
but for 10 entries it is not showing.
drawCallback: () => {
    $('.paginate_button.page-item').on('click', () => {
        this.isAllCheck();
    });
    $('.dataTables_filter input').on('keyup', () => {
        this.isAllCheck();
    });

    // For search pagination checks
    const value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
    this.frontEndSearchData(value);
}

frontEndSearchData(value) {
    if(value.toString().trim()) {
        this.isSearchActive = true;
    } else {
        this.isSearchActive = false;
        return;
    }
    const table = $('#capturePacketTableId').DataTable();
    const info = table.page.info();
    this.searchFilterData = info;
}

Expecting to show all the records matching the input, but none is showing when only 10 entries are selected. but results are showing when 50 entries are selected.
